# prevent interface from having property with name X

Tags: typescript, interface

I have this interface :

```
interface Config {
    height : number;
    width : number;
    [propName : string] : any;
}
```

as you can see I have `[propName : string] : any` which allow me to have any other properties but I need to disallow property with the name `key` for example.

in other words I want to allow any other property but `key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an additional property `key?: undefined` to `Config`:

```
interface Config {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    key?: undefined; // add this line
    [propName: string]: any;
}

const res1: Config = { height: 3, width: 4, me: "too" } // works
const res2: Config = { height: 3, width: 4, me: "too", key: "dsaf" } // error
```

Comment: Note: replaced `never` with `undefined`, as `undefined` | `never` resolves to `undefined`, so it doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: haha, you are right. I would love to write something like `type Config = {...} & not {key: any}` with a negated type. If `key: undefined` has to also excluded, maybe introducing a type parameter with an "key" checking conditional type could be a thing and using this type in functions.

Comment: like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZM5ACwlwrAC5kQBXAWwCNoBuE85Ad2AATMBQbN2XHuQDaAByjpZAOTgsIDAM5gooHAF0GcEAE9uxAL4kwx2SgCiANzgAbDFlwAeACrIIAD0gQQQ00TGwcAD5kAF4CZGkAaWRQZABrCGN0GGQvA2Qk-0Dg5AAidOMS5AB+RggHaGQGL0S9ZEtiEhgmEAQwYExkQXQAZXQ1EV1vXwCIIJC3cIiACjqXVBgcBkc1sM8vCIBKOPaSIdHxil0l-EpqHFoGAGYAGn4hEQYAFle1BhKwdDoSrmA6nEZjCATEA4a63Gj0ZAvN7CUTIb7IX6lAFA17lP5sZxwYGg4hnCFQmE3Kjwp6vAQor4-dRYwElXEZBjdQQQbAgCCCNokoA)